# Regular expression for all lower case with _ allowed

Tags: regex

what is the regular expression to validate a string. the string should contain

1. all lower case
2. _ is allowed in the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Learn regex](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Comment: All lower case: does this include `ñ` for instance? Or what about `כ`?

Comment: Where do you want to use your regex? Perl, PHP, JavaScript, C#, VIM etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regex pattern

```
^[a-z_]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a POSIX class as an alternative to a simple character class to achieve this:

`[[:lower:]_]*`